# How can I get the sum total of a column in the gridview to a textbox outside the gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridviewcolumn

In asp.net C#, How can I get the sum total of a column in the gridview to a textbox outside the gridview?

Note: Gridview data is not coming from any database it is being entered manually by the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call this Method on some button click or on new row creation or whatever event you want to

```
    private void GrandTotal()
    {
     float GTotal = 0f;
     for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
        String total = (GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblTotal") as Label).Text;
        GTotal += Convert.ToSingle(total);
     }
     txtTotal.text=GTotal.toString();
    }
```

Hope i helped :D

Comment: when I load without data, I get error as `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` why ?

Comment: It's probably your Gridview1.Rows[i] call. If the Gridview is empty then no object is returned.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    sum +=Convert.ToInt32( GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[/*the column index*/].Text);
}
```

Comment: It depends on when do you want this calculation.

Comment: nope,actually we don't know what you want to do,but use it where need the sumation

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work.

```
int total = 0;
for (int row = 0; row  < GridView1.Rows.Count; row ++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < GridView1.Columns.Count; col++) 
         total +=Convert.ToInt32( GridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Text);
}
```